# Upload photo and tag friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post photo on user wall and tag friends but i'm getting this :

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file
>   thrown in /home/vhosts/somesite.com/src/base_facebook.php on line 1238

This is my code

```
<?php
require_once "./src/facebook.php";

$app_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxx";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

// Get the url to redirect for login to facebook
// and request permission to write on the user's wall.
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array('scope' => 'publish_stream')
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);


// If not authenticated, redirect to the facebook login dialog.
// The $login_url will take care of redirecting back to us
// after successful login.
if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

    exit;
}

// Do the wall post.
$args = array(
  'message' => 'Test Message',
  'image'   => '@' . realpath('http://imageurl.com'),
  'tags'    => array(
     array(
      'tag_uid'=> $friend1_uid,
      'x'      => $x1,
      'y'      => $y1,
     ),
     array(
      'tag_uid' => $friend2_uid,
      'x'       => $x2,
      'y'       => $y2,
     ),/*...*/
   ),
);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);

// Upload Support.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  /*..*/
  'fileUpload'  => true,
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'image'   => '@' . realpath('http://imageurl.com'),
```

realpath is for *file system* paths, not for URLs.

Either change that to a local file system path – or, if you want to upload a photo from a publicly available HTTP URL, use parameter name `url` instead of `source` and give the URL as value.

Comment: I've change it to 'image'   => '@' . realpath('image.jpg'),  and still doesn't work

Comment: Check what realpath returns. And have you turned on file uploading while initializing the Facebook class resp. done it somewhere later?